# python - efficient way of checking if part of string is in the list

Tags: python

I have a huge string like:

> The Dormouse's story. Once upon a time there were three little
>   sisters; and their names were  Elsie, Lacie and Tillie; and they lived
>   at the bottom of a well....badword...

and I have a list of around 400 bad words:

```
bad_words = ["badword", "badword1", ....]
```

what is the most efficient way to check if text contains a bad word from badwords list?

I could loop over both text and list like:

```
for word in huge_string:
   for bw in bad_words_list: 
    if bw in word: 
       # print "bad word is inside text"...
```

but this seems to me to be from 90's..

**Update:** bad words are single words.

Comment: so it can be a substring or actual words? if words use sets.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham actual words for now

Comment: Did you try `set intersection`?

Comment: Do you just want to know if `any` `badwords` are found inside `inputstring`? Or do you want to know which specifics are found?

Comment: @DaanTimmer i want to know if any word from badword list is in inputstring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning your text into a set of words and computing its intersection with the set of bad words will give you amortized speed:

```
text  = "The Dormouse's story. Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were Elsie, Lacie and Tillie; and they lived at the bottom of a well....badword..."

badwords = set(["badword", "badword1", ....])

textwords = set(word for word in text.split())
for badword in badwords.intersection(textwords):
    print("The bad word '{}' was found in the text".format(badword))
```

Comment: I like this solution, should be more efficient than a for loop with a nested `word in text`. P.S: you forgot a `in` in your for loop.

Comment: perfect!  i need exactly that amortized speed. thanks

Answer (score 2):

No need to get all the words of the text, you can directly check if a string is in another string, e.g.:

```
In [1]: 'bad word' in 'do not say bad words!'
Out[1]: True
```

So you can just do:

```
for bad_word in bad_words_list:
    if bad_word in huge_string:
        print "BAD!!"
```

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
st = set(s.split())

bad_words = ["badword", "badword1"]
any(bad in st for bad in bad_words)
```

Or if you want the words:

```
st = set(s.split())

bad_words = {"badword", "badword1"}
print(st.intersection(bad_words))
```

If you have words like where the sentence ends in a  `badword.` or `badword!` then the set method will fail, you will actually have to go over each word in the string and check if any badword is the same as the word or a substring.

```
st = s.split()
any(bad in word for word in st for bad in bad_words)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

To test if bad_words are pre/suffixes:

```
>>> bad_words = ["badword", "badword1"]
>>> text ="some text with badwords or not"
>>> any(i in text for i in bad_words)
True
>>> text ="some text with words or not"
>>> any(i in text for i in bad_words)
False
```

It will compare any of the bad_words' item are in `text`, using "substring".

To test exact matches:

```
>>> text ="some text with badwords or not"
>>> any(i in text.split() for i in bad_words)
False
>>> text ="some text with badword or not"
>>> any(i in text.split() for i in bad_words)
True
```

It will compare any of the bad_words' item are in `text.split()`, that is, if it's an exact item.

Answer (score 1):

`s` is the long string. use `&` operator or [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) method.

```
In [123]: set(s.split()) & set(bad_words)
Out[123]: {'badword'}

In [124]: bool(set(s.split()) & set(bad_words))
Out[124]: True
```

Or even **better** Use [`set.isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint). 
This will short circuit as soon as match is found.

```
In [127]: bad_words = set(bad_words)

In [128]: not bad_words.isdisjoint(s.split())
Out[128]: True

In [129]: not bad_words.isdisjoint('for bar spam'.split())
Out[129]: False
```

Answer (score 1):

On top of all the excellent answers, the `for now, whole words` clause in your comment points in the direction of regular expressions.

You may want to build a composed expression like `bad|otherbad|yetanother`

```
r = re.compile("|".join(badwords))
r.search(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

i would use a `filter` function:

```
filter(lambda s : s in bad_words_list, huge_string.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already a library for that

```py
from better_profanity import profanity
print(profanity.censor("YOUR_TEXT", "#"))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
s = " a string with bad word"
text = s.split()

if any(bad_word in text for bad_word in ('bad', 'bad2')):
        print "bad word found"
```

Comment: That will only print the last bad_word? any just returns true or false if "any" of the elelements in the list are true(thy)