# python to find sub string inside string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and I have simple problem with code below
the code supposed to give the result 'x100' while it is 'x10' and 'x100'.How to get the result as expected.

```
test_list=['x10','x50','x100']
text='this text has x100 only'
for i in test_list:
    if  text.find(i)!=-1:
        print "found "+i 
>>> 
found x10
found x100
>>>
```

Comment: `if i in text.split():`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620573/python-efficient-way-of-checking-if-part-of-string-is-in-the-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way would be

```
test_list=['x10','x50','x100']
text='this text has x100 only'
for i in test_list:
    if  i in text.split():
        print "found "+i
```

To detect

```
test_list=['x10','x50','x100']
test_list= sorted(test_list,key = lambda x: len(x), reverse = True)
text='this text has x100n only'
import re
a = re.search("|".join(test_list),text)
if a:
    print "Found",a.group()
```

Comment: what about this text 'this text has x100n only'?

Comment: @user3522379 That does not work. Do you want that also?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.split()` to find if it's in the list of word:

```
>>> test_list=['x10','x50','x100']
>>> text='this text has x100 only'
>>> for i in test_list:
...   if i in text.split():
...     print "found",i
...
found x100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple list-comprehension to find all instances. Bonus: it only calculates the split once.

```
def f(s, lst):
    return [item for item in lst if item in s.split()]
```

Test it:

```
>>> test_list=['x10','x50','x100']
>>> text='this text has x100 only'
>>> f(text, test_list)
['x100']
```